# How to get the list of users who are currently logged in Flask-Login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

In my **Flask-SQLAlchemy** web application I have implemented **Flask-Login** for user authentication and authorization. Now I am building an Admin section where the admin user can add, edit or delete any user and view user list. So before deleting any user I want to know whether that user is currently logged in to the application from somewhere or simply having any active session with the web application. How can I accomplice this? Or Is this even possible in the application level?

[**Note:** As you can see, this is **NOT about** `current_user.is_authenticated`]

Comment: You need to use socket to know the list of users  is currently logged in.

Comment: Another possible solution: Add is_login to user table. when user log in, is_login=true and when user is log out, is_login=false. But this solution has some disadvantages. For example, when the user log in then close the browser without log out.

Comment: Yes I thought about that. But there is no way to tap session expired event in flask as per my knowledge. That's a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to implement this feature yourself as there is not a way to do it natively with `flask-login`.

I can think of myriad ways to do this, but the quickest is probably just keeping track of the last time a user accessed your site. Then you can set a reasonable `timeout` where you assume the user is not logged in if they haven't done anything for the last 30 minutes (or however long you feel comfortable with)

For example:

```
@app.before_request
def update_last_active():
    current_user.last_active = datetime.utcnow()
    db.session.commit()
```

This would update `User.last_active` every time the user sends a request to your server.

Comment: Excellent! Simple and easy! Definitely going to try it. But before that I have a few questions. First of all isn't updating database for every user request is a big overhead to the system? Is there any way to accomplice this without manipulating the database? Secondly how to set a session cookie timeout for flask-login? And lastly - should I put this method in my application package init.py file?